# Validate string input in c++ for letters and spaces only

Tags: c++, validation

I haven't got to know a lot about functions yet since I'm just at chapter 4 (which is decision making using if, else) of Starting Out with C++ book. 
Here my problem asks me to enter the inputs of runner names and their timer so I could rank them in 1st 2nd and 3rd place.

I'm having trouble to validate the input for the string for runners's names as letters and spaces only. 
I'm thinking about using loop or bool but I don't know what is the proper way to put it.

Can somebody show me what function I can use best in this case without repeating step into multiple lines of codes.
I'm sorry in advance for my long version code, I'm also looking for the way to shorten it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip> // for setw, setpresicion, control output
#include <cctype> // for getline, cin.

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string runner1, runner2, runner3;
    double time1, time2, time3;


    cout << "Enter Runner 1 name: ";
    getline(cin, runner1);
    cout << "Enter Runner 2 name: ";
    getline(cin, runner2);
    cout << "Enter Runner 3 name: ";
    getline(cin, runner3);

    cout << runner1 << "'s finishing time: ";
    cin >> time1;
    while (!cin || (time1 < 0)){              //the # is negative
        cout << "Please enter a non-negative number!\n";
        cin >> time1;
    }
    cout << runner2 << "'s finishing time: ";
    cin >> time2;
    while (!cin || (time2 < 0)){              //the # is negative
        cout << "Please enter a non-negative number!\n";
        cin >> time2;
    }
    cout << runner3 << "'s finishing time: ";
    cin >> time3;
    while (!cin || (time3 < 0)){
        cout << "Please enter a non-negative number!\n";
        cin >> time3;
    }

    // This is for Rank1----------------------------
        cout << "1st place : ";
        if((time1 < time2)&&(time1 < time3))
        {
            cout << left << setw(5) << runner1 << " " << right
            << setw(5) << time1 << endl;
        }
        else if (time2 < time3){
            cout << left << setw(5) << runner2 << " " << right
            << setw(5)  << time2 << endl;
        }
        else {
            cout << left << setw(5) << runner3 << " " << right
            << setw(5) << time3 << endl;
        }
        //Rank2------------------------------------
        cout << "2nd place : ";
        if ((time1 < time2)&&(time3 < time1)){
            cout << left << setw(5) << runner1 << " " << right
            << setw(5) << time1 << endl;
        }
        else if ((time3 < time2)&&(time1 < time3)){
            cout << left << setw(5) << runner3 << " " << right
            << setw(5) << time3 << endl;
        }
        else {
            cout << left << setw(5) << runner2 << " " << right
            <<setw(5) << time2 << endl;
        }
        // RANK 3-----------------------------------
        cout << "3rd place : ";
        if ((time1 > time2)&&(time1 > time3)){
            cout << left << setw(5) << runner1 << " " << right
            << setw(5) << time1 << endl;
        }
        else if ((time1 < time3)&&(time3 > time2)){
            cout << left << setw(5) << runner3 << " " << right
            << setw(5) << time3 << endl;
        }
        else {
            cout << left << setw(5) << runner2 << " " << right
            <<setw(5) << time2 << endl;
        }



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't use `std::endl` when all you want to say is `'\n'` (`"...\n..."`). If you \*really\* want to flush the stream then be explicit and use `std::flush`. Also, `std::getline()` and `std::cin` are not declared in `<cctype>`

Comment: `bool Validate(std::string const& str) { return std::all_of(str.begin(), str.end(), [](char ele){ return isalpha(ele) || ele == ' '; }); }`

Comment: @George OP: "I'm just at chapter 4" ... i doubt that captures (no pun) lambdas

Comment: @Swordfish I know, that's why I left it as a comment :) The op could pick it apart and write it without the lambda, or just take it if no one answers.

Comment: Anytime you write "cin >> something" make sure you check the error. Rewrite as "if((cin >> something).fail()) { // handle error }" See return value: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/

Comment: @George You should probably add a `static_cast` because [`std::isalpha()` expects a value representable as an unsigned char](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalpha). Also, there is `std::isspace()`.

Comment: @George thank you for your response. I saw these codes earlier on other sites too but I couldn't follow it  But it'll come in handy later on for me.

Comment: @HanBui -- *I saw these codes earlier on other sites too but I couldn't follow it* -- There is hardly anything to really follow.  A couple of syntax issues but that's all there is.  If you read the line of code out loud, it practically describes what it does.  "*return true if all_of the characters between the begin() of the string and end() of the string are either alpha() or is a space*".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This routine will do the validation:

```
bool validateString(const std::string& s)
{
    for (const char c : s) {
        if (!isalpha(c) && !isspace(c))
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around it. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use something like

```
#include <cctype>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string foo;

    bool valid;
    do {
        std::getline(std::cin, foo);

        valid = true;
        for (std::size_t i{}; i < foo.length() && valid; ++i) {
            if (!(std::isalpha(static_cast<unsigned char>(foo[i])) ||
                  std::isspace(static_cast<unsigned char>(foo[i]))))
                valid = false;
        }
    } while (!valid);
}
```

which checks every character for being a letter or a space.

Answer (score -1):

Here is my proposal for a solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

bool validateString(std::string toCheck) {

bool correct = false;

for (int i = 0; i<toCheck.length(); i++) {

    if ((toCheck[i] >= 65 && toCheck[i] <= 90) || (toCheck[i] >= 97 && toCheck[i] <= 122) || toCheck[i] == 32) {
        correct = true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

return correct;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << validateString("Whats up peeps") << std::endl;
    std::cout << validateString("234235") << std::endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Using [ASCII Table](http://www.asciitable.com/).

**Note:** Might not be the best way to do it but it works.

Comment: don't use magic numbers. if you want to say 'A' then write 'A'.

Comment: @Swordfish, I don't know what you're talking about but whatever

Comment: @PlayBoi_Darski ASCII isn't the only character set that can be used with C++ (though it is the most common). It's almost always preferable to use a char rather than digit representation to make the code's intent clear without having to refer to some character table and make it portable.

Comment: On the portability note, alpha characters are not guaranteed to be contiguous by the C++ standard. I don't know of any char set where that's the case, but it might be handy to know as it would mean that a different approach would be needed for production code.

Comment: @PlayBoi_Darski you should write `if ((toCheck[i] >= 'A' && toCheck[i] <= 'Z') || (toCheck[i] >= 'a' && toCheck[i] <= 'z') || toCheck[i] == ' ')` for better readability.

Comment: @PlayBoi_Darski Use `isalpha()`, not magic numbers such as 65 and 97, and not assume characters lie in the contiguous range.  The `isalpha()` knows whether what you give it is an alphabetic character, regardless of what system is being used, ASCII, EBCDIC, etc.